# Detects if the user only scrolls the first time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know if the user scrolls for the first time only and does not repeat, which means that it detects that it scrolls once and then runs an example code With Javascript :

```
window.onscroll = function (e) { alert('Welcome'); }
```

The problem is in the code. If the user keeps scrolling more than once, the alert('Welcome'); icon will run more often
I want it to only work for the first time, then if it keeps scrolling, it does nothing
Can this be done via javascript?

Comment: You can try to add an event listener when the page loads and then remove it after the first scroll is detected

Comment: Maybe you could try to set a timer - and as soon the user scrolls for the first time you start it, as soon as onscroll is called again you reset it but when the user hasn't scrolled for - let's say 400 ms - you will stop any further action or do what ever you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) which *Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type*:

```
$(window).one('scroll', function (e) { alert('Welcome') });
```

The solution depends on jQuery, but seems like you may have that available because the question is tagged with `jquery`.

Hopefully that helps!